# (q/kdb+) replace left number in a pair by zero if both numbers are equal

Tags: kdb

Having the example

```
(7.5 7.5;5.1 5.5;0.0 3.0;1.0 1.0)

index   value
0   7.5 7.5
1   5.1 5.5
2   0 3f
3   1 1f
```

How can I replace the left number by zero in each pair if both numbers are equal?

example output

```
index   value
0   0 7.5
1   5.1 5.5
2   0 3f
3   0 1f
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dot amend too on the vectors

```
q)a:(7.5 7.5;5.1 5.5;0.0 3.0;1.0 1.0)
q){.[x;(where (=) . flip x;0);:;0f]} a
0   7.5
5.1 5.5
0   3
0   1
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to do this would be to use the `each` adverb.

`{$[x[0]=x[1];0,x[1];x]} each (7.5 7.5;5.1 5.5;0.0 3.0;1.0 1.0)`

Here the if/else function on the left takes a two item list, and returns the list, with 0 replacing the first item if both items match. The each adverb applys this function individually to each pair of numbers in the list.

Comment: You should prepend `0f` rather than `0` to avoid creating mixed lists

Answer (score 3):

```
{(x[;0]*not x[;0]=x[;1]),'x[;1]} value
```

This function should maintain decent performance as the list length gets very large

Comment: Any difference in terms of performance between this version and the dot notation from your initial answer?

Comment: Using the dot notation I used first `.[=]'[x]` is less efficient because has to cycle through each pair. Using Sean's dot notation `(=) . flip x` is more efficient because it keeps it as a vector operation but avoids the explicit indexing of `x[;0]=x[;1]`